# Facebook Logout Url

Tags: flash, facebook, air

I'm working on an android application. The application is not based on Facebook but I added a "share" function to let the user to share of some information on Facebook.

The problem is, I'm using Air for Android developing kit, and I'm using StageWebView class to let the user go into facebook. And I made a "logout" button so the user can logout after shared. It was working as well until two weeks ago. As I learned facebook made some changes again.

I was using a simple URL to logout the user ;

```
swv.loadURL("http://m.facebook.com/logout.php")
```

but now its not working. It's just redirects to home. **I need a URL link that logouts the user**. What should i do to logout the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue today that you have, after a little digging in to the PHP SDK it looks like Facebook now requires the user's access_token to be passed.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

```
public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
    return $this->getUrl(
        'www',
        'logout.php',
        array_merge(array(
            'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
            'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
        ), $params)
    );
}
```

also the url looks like it needs to be https://www. not http://m.

here is my string that now works fine,

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next={0}&access_token={1}
```

where {0} is my URL that FB will redirect to and {1} is the users valid access token.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While I came to the same conclusion, I have not been able to make it work using a javascript redirect.